# Increase upload_max_filesize on GoDaddy linux servers?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Already tried:

```
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
```

in the .htaccess folder and it just spits out an Internal Server Error

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a php.ini file change the default vals to these, upload it to your root.

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Make sure your php.ini is named php5.ini

Comment: already did, doesnt work. or does the php.ini need to be in the upload directory and not just the root?

Comment: Could try it in the upload and see if that works. You should be able to put php.ini's in any directory and they should override the defaults. Also make sure you have your php.ini named php5.ini

Answer (score 0):

Check the following links from godaddy, this is worked for me.

The first link will provide information about, how to change upload limit.
The second link will said, where to change.

[php-upload-limits](https://in.godaddy.com/help/php-upload-limits-on-shared-hosting-1475)
 [what-filename-does-my-php-initialization-file-need-to-use](https://in.godaddy.com/help/what-filename-does-my-php-initialization-file-need-to-use-8913)